# Change schema, execute query and write output to file

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, oracle-manageddataaccess

I want to connect to a database with sys user. Change the schema to a differnt user. Execute a query and write the result into a file.

I am using oralce managed data access .https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/

I have tried three different ways already.

1.) spool-> does not work since I am not executing sqlplus but connect with managedDataAccess

2.) begin execute immediate'changeschema' execute immediate 'query' end -> no output on the reader because of begin/end

3.) try to change the connection conn.ChangeDatabase(user); does not work with managedDataAccess

This is my connection string:

```
string oradb = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=" + host + ")(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=" + instance + ")));User Id = " + oracleUser + "; Password =" + oraclePassword;
```

Can I change the schema within the connection string

Comment: Which database are you using? You tagged mysql and oracle, Can't be both. Please correct the tags.

Comment: fixed it :) sorry

Comment: No problem, common mistake.

Comment: did you specify user that you want to connect as DBA

Answer (score 0):

If you connect as SYS you don't need to change the schema, you can just reference the schema in your from clause, e.g.

```
select * 
from my_user.my_tab
;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already know that but this is more of a workaround than a solution for me. I am executing custom queries and  entering a vairable into the query is not wanted.

Comment: you can have SYS have a synonym to your owner.table_name.